# ionic 3 input item shows no caret on iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 app.
On a page I have a form with some fields.

```
        <form>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>First item</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            ... some more simple fields ...
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Item below keyboard region</ion-label>
                <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="description" name="description"></ion-textarea>
            </ion-item>
            <button ion-button type="submit" block>Add Todo</button>
        </form>
```

When I tab the first, the keyboard is shown and the input item is properly focussed, that is: shows a blinking caret.

Though, when I click a field at a position below the area needed to show the keyboard, I do not get a caret, although the field is actually focussed. When I type, the karakters are put in the field.

The main difference is that when clicking on the lower field, the form is shifted upwards when the keyboard shows.

How to fix this?

I am running the app on an iPad 2017, iOS 11.2.2.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --release",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "^4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "^1.0.9",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.6.5",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-calendar": "^4.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^1.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-privacyscreen": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-windows": "^5.0.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^2.2.1",
    "plist": "^2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {
        "CALENDAR_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app uses your calendar to plan sessions."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-privacyscreen": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "call-number": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This allows",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This allows",
        "FILE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app uses your files to upload on sessions.",
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "windows",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: 'delay'})
],
```

in app.component.ts:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        console.log('Platform is ready!');
        this.keyboard.disableScroll(false);
        ...
```

thanks!

Comment: Have you had any luck with this one?  I am having the same issues.

Comment: I have found a solution, but I'm not sure at all if it is a good way... it's a bit hackish... I will try to add an answer to this question, but give some time...

Comment: @user2158259, I added my hackish solution. Please don't consider this as a real solution. I hope this may trigger others to improve or point to a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I have this **hackish solution**, but I guess there have to be a better one. But because of the comment of user2158259, I'll post it anyway. Please don't punish me for posting it ;-)

1) Remove packages/plugins if you have them:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove ionic-plugin-keyboard
npm uninstall ionic-plugin-keyboard --save
npm uninstall @ionic-native/keyboard --save
```

2) Remove any references in app.module.ts such as

```
this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

3) create a sub-folder in the app-folder and add these two files:

*device.service.ts*
The following code is a subset of my device.service.ts

```
import {ApplicationRef, EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {

    public onTick: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    private tickValue = new Date().getTime();


    constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) {

        window.addEventListener('onresize', () => {
            console.log('DeviceService: on resize');
            this.doTick();
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.doTick();
            }, 100);
        }, false);

        window.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            console.log('transition ended');
            this.doTick();
        }, false);

        this.tickValue = new Date().getTime();
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.doTick();
        });

    }

    /**
     * getTickValue() returns a different value when something changed (orientation, keyboard up/down).
     * by adding this to the screen, the Ionic caret will be adjusted properly
     */
    getTickValue(): string {
        return this.tickValue + ' ' + window.innerWidth + ' ' + window.innerHeight + ' ' + window.orientation;
    }

    doTick(): void {
        this.tickValue = new Date().getTime();
        this.onTick.emit(String(this.tickValue));
        this.appRef.tick();
    }

}
```

*kb-scroll.ts*

```
import {ApplicationRef, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {DeviceService} from './device.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[kb-scroll]' // Attribute selector
})
export class KbScrollDirective {

    constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef,
                public elm: ElementRef,
                public renderer: Renderer2,
                public device: DeviceService) {
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick($event) {
        let elmClickedY;
        let scrollContent: HTMLElement;

        if ('TEXTAREA' === this.elm.nativeElement.tagName) {
            scrollContent = $event.toElement;
            elmClickedY = $event.offsetY;
        } else if ('ION-CONTENT' === this.elm.nativeElement.tagName) {
            // calculate Y offset between click and top of scroll-content area
            scrollContent = this.elm.nativeElement.querySelector('.scroll-content');
            if (scrollContent) {
                // $event.offsetY is most likely small offset in clicked input field in scroll content
                // calculate the offsetY opposed to the container (div.scroll-content)
                let clickScreenY = $event.toElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + $event.offsetY;
                let scrollContentScreenY = scrollContent.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                elmClickedY = clickScreenY - scrollContentScreenY;
            } else {
                console.warn('KbScrollDirective: could not find .scroll-content div in ', this.elm.nativeElement);
            }
        } else {
            console.warn('KbScrollDirective: Can\'t handle ', this.elm.nativeElement.tagName);
        }

        //TODO: OK to 'RE-ASSIGN' window.onresize ?
        window.onresize = () => {
            if (scrollContent) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    let elmHeight = scrollContent.clientHeight;
                    if (elmClickedY > elmHeight) {
                        let toScroll = elmClickedY - elmHeight;
                        scrollContent.scrollTop += toScroll + 40;
                        this.device.doTick();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) Add this service and directive to you module
5) Use the kb-scroll directive on your `<ion-content>` HTML tag:

```
<ion-content kb-scroll>
    ... your form here ...
</ion-content>
```

6) now comes the really dirty part (and it will become clear why we need the service).
It seems that the repaint of the Ionic caret is triggered when something changes on the screen, so we need to force that.

I added a `<span>` to my HTML template that holds the root `<ion-nav>` tag:
*app.html*

```
<!-- invisible ticker, needed to get Keyboard caret into place -->
<div style="position: absolute; top:-100px">{{tickValue}}</div>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false" class="root-content"></ion-nav>
```

7) Add this code in your app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

    ...

    tickValue: string;

    constructor(...,
                public device: DeviceService) {

        this.device.onTick.subscribe(tickValue => {
            this.tickValue = tickValue;
        });
    }
```

So whenever the DeviceService#tickValue get's updated, this subscriber will update the app component's tick-value, causing a repaint of the screen, although the tick value is rendered outside the visible area of the screen. This seems to cause the Ionic caret to be positioned correctly.

**Bonus**: this also works for a textarea that takes more place than half the screen (= screen height - keyboard height). Just add the kb-scroll directive to your `<textarea>` HTML tag.

Please note this is a very hackish solution.

Any comments/improvements are really welcome!